# boto3 introspect user aws configuration to determine mfa_serial in profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

**TL;DR**

There doesn't seem to be a good way to introspect the AWS configuration (CLI) to determine if a profile requires an MFA token for STS and boto doesn't manage this automatically.

I've tried creating a `client` such that something like this could be used for introspection:

```
       c = boto3.client('sts', region_name = region,)
       print('{}'.format(c.mfa_serial))
       time.sleep(1)
```

which just yields:

```
'STS' object has no attribute 'mfa_serial'
```

So yeah, that makes sense. So I tried a session, too:

```
        session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name = profile['name'],
                                        region_name  = region,)
        import time
        print('{}'.format(session.mfa_serial))
        time.sleep(1)
```

which yields:

```
'Session' object has no attribute 'mfa_serial'
```

**Summary**

context:

- we have several accounts

  - one's `$HOME/.aws/credentials` usually contains a few *accounts* IE:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id...
aws_secret_access_key...

[org1-admin]
aws_access_key_id...
aws_secret_access_key...
mfa_serial...

[org2-admin]
aws_access_key_id...
aws_secret_access_key...

[org3-admin]
aws_access_key_id...
aws_secret_access_key...
...
```

- one of these accounts (org1-admin as noted by the presence of `mfa_serial`) uses sub-accounts so there's a config

  - The contents of the `$HOME/.aws/config` defines profiles under one of the aforementioned specified accounts:

```
[profile gen3-prod]
role_arn = ...
source_profile = org3-admin

[profile gen3-preprod]
role_arn = ...
source_profile = org3-admin

[profile gen3-dev]
role_arn = ...
source_profile = org3-admin
```

So the problem:

We have an inventory CLI tool which needs to do resource querying. The problem is that MFA was recently set to forced for only one of the main accounts `org1-admin`. The CLI tool needs to be able to ask the CLI admin for their MFA token *if the CLI tool is querying against `org1-admin` resources* and then assume an sts role just for that account. That's fine. The problem is that there is no reason for the script to attempt to query for MFA until it's necessary (when it needs to seek resources from org1-admin).

Since boto doesn't seem to be intelligent enough to notice when an account requires MFA for authorization, I need to code this in. My main problem is that I'm not really sure how to introspect the boto3 object to see if `mfa_serial` exists.

Comment: How about having your program parse the `config` file and check for `mfa_serial` there?

Comment: That is an option, but it's more work than I'd prefer do if the boto framework already provides a way to do it. If it doesn't then of course that's my only option.

Comment: It could use: [configparser — Configuration file parser — Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)

Comment: yeah, already started implementing and already used configparser. It's a little wonky but it will probably work. It's just unfortunate that the library doesn't already expose this ability since it obviously has to parse these files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the issue I posted [here](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2904), the following was suggested and works well for me:

> Thanks for your patience. There are a few different ways you could do this,
> but from within `boto3/botcore` [sic] itself, you could use the `full_config`
> botocore session object method:

```
import botocore.session

session = botocore.session.Session()
config = session.full_config
```

> Which generates an object containing profiles in your config file. You could
> also use something like the Python ini parser or the AWS CLI's configure get method.